# How long will datetime64 and timedelta64 remain experimental for?

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, datetime64

The [numpy manual for version 1.12](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.datetime.html) states on the topic of datetimes and timedeltas:

> Note
>
> The datetime API is experimental in 1.7.0, and may undergo changes in future versions of NumPy.

NumPy 1.7.0 was apparently released [in February 2013](https://lwn.net/Articles/537828/), version 1.8.0 dates from [October 2013](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-announce-list/2013-October/010091.html), and version 1.9.0 was released in [October 2014](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.numeric.general/58741).  Version 1.12 is expected late 2016 or early 2017.

Are there any concrete plans to stabilise the NumPy `datetime64` and `timedelta64` APIs?  If yes, is there a target version beyond which we can expect such stabilisation?  Or are there some major unsolved problems and should we expect it to remain experimental for the time being?

Comment: You should probably ask the developers. [It looks like there might be some open bugs still](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues?q=datetime64)

Comment: It is possible to declare the API to be stable even if there are outstanding bugs in the current implementation.

Comment: Yes. maybe they just haven't updated the docs. You could open an issue asking for the docs to clarify if the api is still experimental in the latest version.

Comment: Why the downvote?